# Swapping Row Fields in access reports

Tags: ms-access, group-by, report, swap

I am making report in access 2003. I have applied grouping in that report.There are two rows under each group. Now i want to swap one of the field named "Store" under the group. Can anybody help please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to design view, grab the field, move it horisontally to pass the field to swap, save report.